# Pointer to this* in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class and a library (lwip). For some reasons I need to call library's function of thread creation like :

```
/** The only thread function:
 * Creates a new thread
 * @param name human-readable name for the thread (used for debugging purposes)
 * @param thread thread-function
 * @param arg parameter passed to 'thread'
 * @param stacksize stack size in bytes for the new thread (may be ignored by ports)
 * @param prio priority of the new thread (may be ignored by ports) */
sys_thread_t sys_thread_new(const char *name, lwip_thread_fn thread, void *arg, int    
stacksize, int prio);
```

Inside this function we call pthread:

```
code = pthread_create(&tmp,NULL,(void *(*)(void *)) function, arg);
```

My call looks like :

```
sys_thread_new("main_thread",(lwip_thread_fn)&this->main_thread, NULL,   
               DEFAULT_THREAD_STACKSIZE,DEFAULT_THREAD_PRIO);
```

My class method works fine, but I need to change some fielsd of CURRENT class (like 'state'
or else) I have an Idea to pass a pointer to current class to that thread and in thread function change class fields. Some kind of:

```
 sys_thread_new("main_thread",(lwip_thread_fn)&this->main_thread, (void*)this,  
                DEFAULT_THREAD_STACKSIZE, DEFAULT_THREAD_PRIO);
```

Then in main_thread:

```
void lwip::main_thread(void *arg) {
lwip *p = (lwip*)arg;
 p->state = 1;
}
```

Something like that. But it seems I do something wrong -

```
     Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 [Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6e8e700 (LWP 4985)]
 0x0000000000403a75 in lwip::main_thread (this=0x7fffffffe4f0, arg=0x80) at    
 ../src/lwip.cpp:50
 50         p->state = 1;
```

Comment: Did you debug to see if inside `main_thread` `p` has the same value as `this`? BTW, `main_thread` should return `void*`.

Comment: Is `lwip::main_thread` a static function?  You can't use a non-static member function as a thread because pthreads doesn't call it the way a non-static function needs to be called.

Comment: That's why C-cast should be avoided. Compiler should have warned on `(lwip_thread_fn)&this->main_thread` without the cast.

Comment: The most obvious: why the cast of the function pointer in `pthread_create`?  If you have to cast, the code is wrong.  The type of the function pointer is `extern "C" void* (*)(void*)`, and if your function is anything else, you have undefined behavior if you cast it to make it compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to cast the pointer to function to get
`pthread_create` to compile, you have undefined behavior.

If the goal is to call a member function in a different thread,
you need to wrap the call in an `extern "C"` function.  This
means no members and no templates; in the simplest case:

```
extern "C" void*
startThread( void* p )
{
    static_cast<T*>(p)->f();
}
```

and pass the address of `startThread` as third argument and
a pointer to the object as fourth.  If inheritance is involved,
you must ensure that the fourth argument has the same type as
that in the cast in `startThread`, e.g.:

```
pthread_create( &tmp, nullptr, &startThread, static_cast<Base*>( pointerToDerived ) );
```

if `startThread` casts to `Base*`.

If you need arguments to the function as well, you need to pass
a pointer to a struct with both the pointer to the object and
the additional arguments.  You also need to ensure that the
lifetime of this struct is sufficient, so that there is no risk
of the thread accessing an already inexistant object.  This
often means an additional conditional variable, to ensure that
the thread calling `pthread_create` doesn't continue before the
new thread has made a copy of all of the relevant data.  (Both
Boost threads and the C++11 threads do this for you.  It's only
necessary if you need additional data, other than just the
pointer to the object, in the new thread.)

This can get painful if you need to do it for many different
types, and downright impossible if the class in question is
a template.  In such cases, one common solution is to use
a `Thread` object, along the lines of:

```
class Thread
{
public:
    virtual void* run() = 0;
};
```

and a starter function:

```
namespace {
extern "C" void*
doStartThread( void* p )
{
    return static_cast<Thread*>( p )->run();
}
}

pthread_t
startThread( Thread* thread )
{
    pthread_t results;
    if ( pthread_create( &results, nullptr, doStartThread, thread ) != 0 ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Could not create thread" );
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you inherit from `Thread`, overriding the `run`
function with whatever you want (and adding any additional data
you might need); the derived class can even be a template.

Again, the lifetime of the `Thread` object is an issue; the
solution I've usually used has been to require it to be
dynamically allocated, and then delete it at the end of
`doStartThread`.  It's a very good idea to catch it in an
`std::unique_ptr` in `doStartThread`, although you still want to
catch exceptions in this function, since otherwise they will
kill the process.  And don't forget the `delete` if
`pthread_create` fails (since the caller has passed over
ownership.  If you really want to be sure:

```
namespace {
extern "C" void*
doStartThread( void* p )
{
    std::unique_ptr<Thread*> object( static_cast<Thread*>( p ) );
    try {
        return object->run();
    } catch ( ... ) {
        return somethingElseToReportTheError;
    }
}
}

pthread_t
startThread( std::unique_ptr<Thread> thread )
{
    pthread_t results;
    if ( pthread_create( &results, nullptr, doStartThread, thread.get() ) != 0 ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Could not create thread" );
    }
    thread.release();   //  AFTER the call has succeeded!
}
```

I've used this technique successfully in a number of
applications (using `std::auto_ptr`, since there was no
`std::unique_ptr` then); typically, the fact that you need to
use dynamic allocation is not an issue, and it solves the
lifetime issue quite nicely.  (The alternative would be to use
a conditional variable, blocking the original thread until the
new thread had copied everything over.)

Note that by using a `unique_ptr` in the interface, you
effectively block the calling thread from further access to the
thread object, by robbing it of its pointer to the object.  This
offers an additional guarantee with regards to thread safety.
But of course, this additional guarantee (and the solution to
the lifetime issues) only applies to the `Thread` object itself,
and *not* to anything it might point to.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here: If the `main_thread` member function is a static member function, you pass a pointer to it using `&lwip::main_thread`, no casting should be needed. If the function is *not* `static`, then you must make it `static`.

The other problem is that if the instance (`this`) you pass to the thread function is destructed, the thread function now has a pointer to a destructed object. Be careful with temporary object or passing instances by value.

---

If the actual thread function can't be `static`, you can easily solve it with a static wrapper function:

```
class lwip
{
    ...

private:
    void main_thread() { ... }

    static void* main_thread_wrapper(void* arg)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<lwip*>(arg)->main_thread();
        return nullptr;
    }
};

...

sys_thread_new("main_thread", &lwip::main_thread_wrapper, this,
           DEFAULT_THREAD_STACKSIZE,DEFAULT_THREAD_PRIO);
```

Comment: no, it is not static. And I need It to be non-static.

Comment: @RedCollarPanda Then you can't call it properly. All non-static member function have a hidden first argument that becomes the `this` pointer. If you have access to a C++11 capable compiler, you might want to look into the new [thread functionality in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: Is there any way to use multi-thread system without static meembers?

Comment: @RedCollarPanda Yes you can work around it by having a static wrapper member function as the thread function, which calls the non-static member function.

Comment: The point is - I think I'll need to make multiply class objects - so I need to make theese methods non-static.

Comment: @RedCollarPanda And I'm saying you can do that with a static wrapper function. Please see my updated answer for an example. Just by having a static member function doesn't mean you can only create a single thread using it. You can create any number of threads using the same function.

Comment: You cannot legally pass a pointer to a static member function to `pthread_create` (although many compilers fail to enforce this); the function argument _must_ be an `extern "C"` function, and `extern "C"` is ignored for class members, even static.